# What is a multilevel pointer?

Tags: c++, c, pointers, constants, const-cast

When reading about [`const_cast`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) I came across sentences like the following:

> Only the following conversions can be done with const_cast. In particular, only const_cast may be used to cast away (remove) constness or volatility.
>
> 1) Two possibly **multilevel pointers** to the same type may be converted between each other, regardless of cv-qualifiers at each level.

I've googled around a bit already and haven't found any concise, straightforward definitions of what a multilevel pointer is. So: what exactly is a multilevel pointer?

(Possible face-palm moment) It it just a pointer to a pointer, or pointer to a pointer to a pointer, e.g. `int **` or `int ***`?

Comment: Yes a multilevel pointer is something like `T**` or `T***` or even `T********`

Comment: The draft standard does not explicitly define it but it does give you enough information to figure out in section `4.4 Qualification conversions`. Seems like they assume it is common knowledge.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Is it just a pointer to a pointer, or pointer to a pointer to a pointer, e.g. `int **` or `int ***`?

It is exactly this, yes.